# Hibernate - ManyToOne relationship - unable to find entity with id error

Tags: java, hibernate

Please find below classes

AbstractReview.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="REVIEW")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="REVIEW_TYPE")
@Audited
public class AbstractReview{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="reviewGenerator", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name="reviewGenerator",sequenceName="REVIEW_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name="REVIEW_ID")
Long reviewId;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="review", fetch = FethcType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, tragetEntity = ReviewApproval.class)
private Set<ReviewApproval> = new HashSet<>();

}
```

ApprovalDetails.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="APPROVAL_DETAIL")
@Audited
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="APPROVAL_TYPE", discriminatorType= DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
public class ApprovalDetails{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="approvalDetailIdGenerator", strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@SequenceGenerator(name="approvalDetailIdGenerator",sequenceName="APPROVAL_DETAIL_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name="APPROVAL_DETAIL_ID")
Long approvalDetailId;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "APPROVER_CONTACT_ID", referencedColumnName = "CONTACT_ID", nullable = false)
Contact contact;

}
```

ReviewApproval.java

```
@Entity
@Audited
@DiscriminatorValue("REVIEW")
public class ReviewApproval extends ApprovalDetails{

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.Lazy)
@JoinColumn(name="REVIEW_ID", referencedColumnName="REVIEW_ID")
AbstractReview review

}
```

**DB Structure:**

Table - APPROVAL_DETAIL

```
APPROVAL_DETAIL_ID - PK
MEMO_ID - FK
REVIEW_ID - FK
```

Table - Contact

```
CONTACT_ID - PK
MEMO_ID - FK
```

Table - REVIEW

```
REVIEW_ID - PK
```

**Issue Details:**

When new contact is added, corresponding review approval Entity is set in review object and below line works fine. If Contacts reviewApprovalInd is true then corresponding entry is created in ReviewApproval. If reviewApprovalInd is changed from true to false then corresponding entry is deleted from ReviewApproval. Both cases are working fine with below code.

```
reviewService.update(review); <- which uses entityManager.merge
```

but above code gives issue, if any existing contact's reviewApprovalInd is changed from No to Yes then it throws `EntityNotFoundException : Unble to find ReviewApproval with id : 62001`

Code to associate approval with review:

```
if(contact.ApprovalInd){
ReviewApproval app = new ReviewApproval();
app.setContact(contact);
app.setReview(this);
this.getReviewApproval().add(app);
}
```

I have tried adding `@Ignore` on @`ManyToOne` annotation but still issue persists.
Can anyone please help.

Comment: Can you paste the code, that causes the error?

Comment: @Andronicus I have updated code. Error is appearing when review is merged.